# While using Jmeter's selenium webdriver addon, my selector or action code doesn't seem to be working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I'm picking up someone's JMeter project at work and attempting to add some extra code to it for some extra functionality. It should be simple, since all I want to do is login. But I can't seem to send the text to the text fields. I then tried an even simpler one by going to google and just searching for something, and then an even simpler one of just clicking the gmail link. None of these happen though. It goes to the website, but then seems to ignore the code below that.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.linkText('Gmail')); //saves 
search field into searchField
searchField.click(); //clicks search field
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.title('Search')); //saves 
search field into searchField
searchField.click(); //clicks search field
searchField.sendKeys(['blazemeter']);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I've tried the second one with sendkeys('blazmeter') and with the brackets as above.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This is using Chromedriver by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your full code then `pkg` is not defined, it breaks on the line where you call it first time.

[image: JMeter WebDriver Error]

So either define it like:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
```

Or use the following workaround:

```
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText('Gmail'))
```

References:

- [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Comment: This worked! I didn't realize I had missed the opening lines in the example I saw. Great answer!